# Which is fast? Using minimagick gem in ruby or using direct system call convert (ImageMagick) in linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, imagemagick, minimagick

I am using a freescale board with low processing capacity. I need to resize images of various sizes into 800x480 pixels. I had used imagemagick to resize it through direct system call. System is taking a lot of time to convert large images. I thought of using minimagick since ruby is also installed in my system for other purposes. I need some advice on the performance of using minimagick( I know Rmagic is slow).

Summary:

1) bash$ convert image1.jpg -resize 800x480 image2.jpg

2) ruby miniconvert.rb

where miniconvert.rb is

```
require 'mini_magick'
image = MiniMagick::Image.open("image1.jpg") 
image.resize "800X480"
image.write("image2.jpg")
```

Which will run faster on a single core low cpu machine with minimal linux installed?
Also, Is minimagick directly using system call (ie, calling convert of imagemagick)?

Comment: You are going to answer this question yourself, right?

Comment: @Stefan: The problem is I don't have full control of the machine. Imagemagick is installed in it but minimagick is not installed. If I could conclude that minimagick is a bit faster than imagemagick, then i can request them to install minimagick in it.

Comment: how you benchmark `minimagick is a bit faster than imagemagick` )?

Comment: if you really have issue with the performance of imagemagick, recommend you take a look at http://www.graphicsmagick.org , which is a much faster fork of imagemagick and largely compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doensn't matter much, because MiniMagick uses the command line tool of ImageMagick as well, according to [its Readme](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) (it uses `mogrify` instead of `convert`).

So… the gem is probably more convenient, the command line probably just a bit faster (no overhead).